# How can I copy locations from one campaign to another in Google Adwords?

Tags: google-ads-api

I have created a new Campaign in Google Adwords, and I want to copy all locations from an existed campaign to the new one. There is no edit button on the setting page, whereas there is an edit button on the keywords page. Is it possible to copy and paste locations?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the AdWords Editor yet? I seem to recall it has more options when it comes to cloning settings and such.

Comment: AdWords Editor is the final choice. It is complicated. I have to download relevant data, make some changes, and upload them again. It's weird that Google didn't add an edit tab like what they've done for keywords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the button you're looking for (I think). Select "All campaigns" in the sidebar > Select the "Settings" tab > Make sure you're viewing "All settings" > on the toolbar above the datatable (same row as "+ CAMPAIGN") on the far right there should be a button labelled "copy locations to" (or something to that extent, I have a different language set) > select a campaign and click the button.

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps an update to ravb79's answer, because it is a little different. I am in the US and using Chrome.

In the left rail, select "All Campaigns"
Check the checkbox for the campaigns you wish to move locations to
Read the above again. You check the campaigns you want to change, NOT the one you are copying FROM. 
 
Go to the "Settings" tab (under the heading "All online campaigns")
Click on the "Edit" button next to the red "+CAMPAIGN" button
Choose "Location..." from the dropdown
Select the radio button next to "Replace with locations from another campaign"
Click on "Choose..."
Slect the campaign FROM which you want to copy locations

I hope this helps.